# Is there a difference between re0 and wlan0?

Tags: freebsd, network-interface, pf

I am new to FreeBSD and trying to set up a firewall with `pf` on my laptop. The machine is connected to the internet via wifi.

On writing rule sets in `/etc/pf.conf`, some [tutorials](https://cooltrainer.org/a-freebsd-desktop-howto/#firewall) say to spell out the network interface to which the rules apply, like so: `ext_if="re0"`. However, `ifconfig` tells me my wireless interface is `wlan0`, while `re0` does not even turn up in ifconfig's output. Using `re0`, `pfctl` does not throw an error, so it seems that `re0` exists. I just don't know what it refers to.

Which should I use?

Answer (score 3):

On FreeBSD the device names are given by the driver, which handles the device.

So when you have a RealTek NIC it is controlled by the `re` driver and to separate multiple NICs which are controlled by the re driver they are numbered starting with 0. See [`man 4 re`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=re&apropos=0&sektion=4&manpath=FreeBSD%2011.1-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html).

`wlan` is a different driver for generic Wi-Fi cards. So when you want to write rules for your Wi-Fi, you should use `wlan0`, since this is your only Wi-Fi device. See [`man 4 wlan`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=wlan&apropos=0&sektion=4&manpath=FreeBSD%2011.1-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html).

The fact that using `re0` doesn't produce an error is strange, but it could be that `pf` can deal with plug and play devices like USB-NICs.

Comment: The fact that you set up rules for a non-existing interface does not bother `pf`, it just won't have any effect.

Comment: @Kusalananda But what would happen if `re0` showed up later? Would one need to reconfigure pf?

Comment: Ah, that I don't know. I'm guessing that the rules would then be in effect on that interface but I have not tested it.

Answer (score 1):

> `ifconfig` tells me my wireless interface is wlan0, while re0 does not even turn up in `ifconfig`'s output.

The `re0` is the name of the Ethernet interface (using the realtek driver `re`).

The `wlan0` is the name of the wireless interface . On this tuto the wireless driver is [`run`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?run(4)) which refer to Ralink wifi device.

```
run -- Ralink Technology USB IEEE 802.11a/g/n wireless network device
```

Adding `wlans_run0="wlan0"` to `rc.conf` allow `ifconfig` to display the wifi interface as `wlan0`

To configure `pf` you should use the exact device name of your Ethernet card and not `re0` (because `re0` isn't listed through `ifconfig` ) , generally the ethernet interface will be configured during the system install , if it is not displayed you should load the kernel module first.

```
ext_if="Ethernet_interface_name"
```